# Spring JPA is not managing a simple INSERT query - Column of relation does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

So I have this simple table for users that I create with this Liquibase script:

```
<createTable tableName="users">
            <column name="id" type="integer">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" unique="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="email" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="username" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="password" type="varchar(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="enabled" type="boolean">
            </column>
        </createTable>
```

Now after that I add the sequence for the `id` column:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE users_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq OWNED BY users.id;
```

Now when I run this insert on the PostgreSQL database manually:

```
insert into users (email, enabled, username, password) values ('user@user.ee', true, 'user', 'user123');
```

But when I use the `saveAndFlush()` method of my interface that extends `JpaRepository`:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Then I have an error thrown in the server like this:

```
2015-12-17 20:12:12.632 DEBUG 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into users (email, enabled, password, username) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-12-17 20:12:12.637  WARN 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2015-12-17 20:12:12.637 ERROR 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column "enabled" of relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 27
2015-12-17 20:12:12.639 DEBUG 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-12-17 20:12:12.639 DEBUG 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5e1f992a
2015-12-17 20:12:12.641 ERROR 17236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "enabled" of relation "users" does not exist
  Position: 27
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:441) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66-internal]
```

As seen from the error, the Hibernate that the JPA repo is using, is executing the exact same query.

Why is this query working manually but not in the code?

Comment: I would guess that JPA and and your SQL client tool are connecting to different databases.

Comment: Well... This is embaressing.. That was exactly the problem. Thanks!